# CSS: how to align images vertically bottom

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
<ol><li><a href=""><span><img src="/images/sized/images/uploads/books/book_1.jpg" width="100" height="165"  alt="" /></span>
  </a> </li>
<li><a href=""><span><img src="/images/sized/images/uploads/books/book_2.jpg" width="100" height="130"  alt="" /></span>
  </a> </li></ol>
```

How do I align the images vertically bottom? (the images have various heights)

Answer (score 9):

Try this

Css

```
li{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:yellow;
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

html

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://2.imimg.com/data2/LQ/QV/MY-/teddy-small-size-250x250.jpg" width="250" height="250" /></li>
</ul>
```

working example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BhkCT/)

hope this will help you.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to vertical-align both the li and the img, and make the li as high as the tallest image. And for semantic's sake, please remove the unnecessary spans.

```
li 
{
    float: left; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 165px; 
    vertical-align: bottom
}

li img 
{
    vertical-align: bottom
}
```

Comment: `vertical-align` needs text to work so you could do something like this: `li::after {
        content: ".";
        visibility: hidden;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Just set `display: inline-block;` for `li` elements:
[working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bfFjp)

Although keep in mind, that it won't work in lte IE7.